# rails how to call the attributes in a table and do the some calculation update another column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to some calculations in the model of table

My table looks like

```
   s.no name place  overallrating  reviews   attrib_r1  attrib_r2  attrib_r3
      1  raj    usa                    2          39       45         46
      2  ravi   india                  4           56       75        85
```

Now I would like to update my overallratings column through my model.

And I have tried like

```
def update_satisfaction

     update_attributes(:satisfaction => self.collect(':attrib_r1','attrib_r2','attrib_r3').sum.to_f/self.reviews)
end
```

But I am getting an error that is collect is undefined and when I check for self.review I am not getting any value I am getting nil.

I dont know am I doing right or wrong. I am learning rails now can any one tell me how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: You are using `self.reviews` Note the extra "s". Is it supposed to be `review` or `reviews`?

Comment: it is reviews. it is the name of the coloumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this method is defined as an instance method in the model, `self` is going to be an instance of that model. So far as I know, ActiveRecord objects do not have a `.collect` method, so it's not surprising that it's undefined.
To take the sum of several attributes, you could simply add them together:

```
(self.attrib_r1 + self.attrib_r2 + self.attrib_r3).to_f/self.reviews
```

In fact, in instance methods, `self` is implied when referring to attributes, so it can be omitted:

```
(attrib_r1 + attrib_r2 + attrib_r3).to_f/reviews
```

You could also put the attributes in an array and sum that, though it is probably slightly less efficient:

```
[attrib_r1, attrib_r2, attrib_r3].sum.to_f/reviews
```

Now, if any of these values are `nil`, this will produce an error (`TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum`, probably), so you'll want to check for that before doing the calculation.